# Javascript table string to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, html-table

I have a *string* that looks like:

```
<tr><td>Date</td><td>Value</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-01-01</td><td>231.198</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-02-01</td><td>232.770</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-03-01</td><td>232.340</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-04-01</td><td>231.485</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-05-01</td><td>231.831</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-06-01</td><td>232.944</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-07-01</td><td>233.318</td></tr>
```

...which is of course essentially a table.

I'd like to dynamically convert this string into an array containing 2 arrays. One of dates, one of values.

[Edited in]
An array of objects with date and values would work too.

Comment: parse it with an html parser.

Comment: are you using any libraries? jQuery could make pretty short work of this... Also, are there reliable newlines?

Comment: Maybe array of {date, value} objects would make more sense?

Comment: I have jquery, but I'd prefer not to use any additional libraries or even jquery pluggins. Would like to keep this light.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter That would work too. I just need something to parse this into a usable manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following::

```
var input = // your string

var output = $(input).slice(1).map(function(i,el) {
    var tds = $(el).find("td");
    return { "date" : tds.eq(0).text(), "value" : tds.eq(1).text() };
}).get();
```

...will return an array of objects in this format:

```
[{"date":"2013-01-01","value":"231.198"}, {"date":"2013-02-01","value":"232.770"}, ... ]
```

If you'd like each `value` to be treated as a number you can convert it like so:

```
    return { "date" : tds.eq(0).text(), "value" : +tds.eq(1).text() };
    // add the unary plus operator ---------------^
```

Then the result will be:

```
[{"date":"2013-01-01","value":231.198}, {"date":"2013-02-01","value":232.77}, ... ]
```

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I haven't checked the source code for this issue, but I would expect that either way jQuery would use the same code under the covers.

Comment: Found it: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11617. And, it may not be (as much of) a concern with 2.0.x and 1.10.x, but it was at one point.

Answer (score 3):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd post a plain JavaScript solution (albeit largely because I spent time working on it, before Barmar pointed out that you're willing and able to use jQuery):

```
function cellContents(htmlStr, what) {
    var _table = document.createElement('table');
    _table.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    var rows = _table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        cells,
        matches = {};
    for (var w = 0, wL = what.length; w < wL; w++) {
        matches[what[w]] = [];
        for (var r = 1, rL = rows.length; r < rL; r++) {
            cells = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
            matches[what[w]].push(cells[w][text]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}

var str = "<tr><td>Date</td><td>Value</td></tr><tr><td>2013-01-01</td><td>231.198</td></tr><tr><td>2013-02-01</td><td>232.770</td></tr><tr><td>2013-03-01</td><td>232.340</td></tr><tr><td>2013-04-01</td><td>231.485</td></tr><tr><td>2013-05-01</td><td>231.831</td></tr><tr><td>2013-06-01</td><td>232.944</td></tr><tr><td>2013-07-01</td><td>233.318</td></tr>";

console.log(cellContents(str, ['dates', 'values']));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v3wG4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

For a pure JavaScript solution you can try something like this (assuming str holds your string) :

```
var arrStr = str.replace(/<td>/g, "").replace(/<tr>/g, "").split("</td></tr>");
var arrObj = [];
var arrData

for (var i = 1; i < arrStr.length - 1; i++) {
    arrData = arrStr[i].split("</td>");
    arrObj.push({ Date: arrData[0], Value: arrData[1] })
}
```

It's a burte-force string replacement/split, but at the end `arrObj` will have array of objects.

Comment: Thank you! In my case this way is good option. May be use `var arrStr = str.replace(/<td>/g, "").replace(/<tr>/g, "").split("</tr>");`?

Answer (score 0):

if its a valid html table structure, wrap it between table tags, and use jquery to parse it.
then use jquery's selectors to find the columns.

e.g something like this ( pseudo code, havent tried it )

```
table = $(yourTableString);
dates  =  table.find("tr td:nth-child(1)");
values =  table.find("tr td:nth-child(2)");
```

Comment: It's not a table - not in the DOM. It's a string - text that's being dynamically ripped out of an excel spreadsheet file

Comment: @DavidThomas He said he has jquery in a comment, it seemed like he's OK with using it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var table = $('<table>'+str+'</table>');
var result = {};
table.find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    var date = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var value = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    result[date] = value;
}
```

`:gt(0)` is to skip over the header line. This will create an associative array object that maps dates to values. Assuming the dates are unique, this is likely to be more useful than two arrays or an array of objects.